# More efficient code

Tags: sql

I have the following code where we need to see our inventories across 17 different locations. The code I have below is just for 5 locations, but works. Looking to see if there is a cleaner more efficient code that we can use to get the same results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT imitmidx_sql.item_no, imitmidx_sql.item_desc_1, imitmidx_sql.item_desc_2,
 (SELECT qty_on_hand FROM iminvloc_sql AS IMINVLOC_SQL_1 WHERE (loc = '1') AND (item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no)) AS Loc1,
 (SELECT qty_on_hand FROM iminvloc_sql AS IMINVLOC_SQL_2 WHERE (loc = '2') AND (item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no)) AS Loc2,
 (SELECT qty_on_hand FROM iminvloc_sql AS IMINVLOC_SQL_3 WHERE (loc = '3') AND (item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no)) AS Loc3,
 (SELECT qty_on_hand FROM iminvloc_sql AS IMINVLOC_SQL_4 WHERE (loc = '4') AND (item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no)) AS Loc4,
 (SELECT qty_on_hand FROM iminvloc_sql AS IMINVLOC_SQL_5 WHERE (loc = '5') AND (item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no)) AS Loc5
FROM iminvloc_sql INNER JOIN imitmidx_sql ON iminvloc_sql.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
```

Comment: Why are you aliasing your table names in your LocN's when you're not even using the alias?

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
select
    imitmidx_sql.item_no,
    imitmidx_sql.item_desc_1,
    imitmidx_sql.item_desc_2,
    itm_loc_qty.*

    from iminvloc_sql

pivot (SUM(qty_on_hand) for loc in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) as itm_loc_qty -- Add here as necessary

join imitmidx_sql
on itm_loc_qty.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
```

Comment: The Op's code essentially pivots the results.  Where there are 5 related ***rows*** in `iminvloc_sql`, the correlated sub-queries yield these as 5 ***fields***.  Your query retains the 5 rows, having not done the pivot.